# electron-builder create .dmg on windows

Tags: macos, electron, exe, electron-builder, dmg

I want to create my electron app installer for windows, mac and linux however currectly it's only creating .exe file:

[image]

and some win-unpacked directory and some other files which I don't even know why I need because .exe file is installing my app and creating desktop shortcut and I don't even need those extra files to get app to work.

In other word - when I just copy .exe and run on other machine then it's succesfully installing therefore why I even need those other files?

---

So it's working correctly with windows but it does not create any files that I could run on macOS and linux like .dmg.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "screenrecorder",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Electron application to record screen",
  "main": "./src/js/main/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ./src/js/main/index.js",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass src/style/scss/main.scss src/style/css/output.css -w",
    "build": "electron-builder"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/d0peCode/screenRecorder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "screenrecorder",
    "mac": {
      "category": "your.app.category.type",
      "target": "dmg"
    }
  },
  "author": "Borys Tyminski",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/d0peCode/screenRecorder#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.5",
    "angular-route": "^1.6.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "^21.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2"
  }
}
```

And this is my log from terminal after running `npm run build`

> C:\Users\Borys\Documents\work\screenRecorder\desktop>npm run build
>
> screenrecorder@1.0.0 build >C:\Users\Borys\Documents\work\screenRecorder\desktop
>
> > electron-builder
>
> • electron-builder  version=21.2.0 os=10.0.18362
>
> • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
>
> • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
>
> • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=6.0.6 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
>
> • default Electron icon is used  reason=application icon is not set
>
> • building        target=nsis file=dist\screenrecorder Setup 1.0.0.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
>
> • building block map  blockMapFile=dist\screenrecorder Setup 1.0.0.exe.blockmap

Why it doesn't create macOS installer? And what are steps to make it do so?

Comment: What OS are you using for development? Also could we see the log output of your build process?

Comment: I use windows 10, I'll edit question with the log

Answer (score 0):

You can not build macOS executables with Electron on Windows as it requires the Apple SDK and XCode tools. Linux works but you need to specify the format and architecture in your build configuration.

For example to build a Linux executable in AppImage format for ARMv7l CPUs you can use this configuration:

```
linux: {
    target: {
        target: 'appimage',
        arch: ['armv7l']
    }
}
```

The full documentation on Linux build options is [available here](https://www.electron.build/configuration/linux).